# How to apply if condition with pandas and write it to new column if the condition satisfies?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply these two condition on the csv file

1.(Total Length of Fwd Packets$ <= 0.00003225 AND Total Length of Fwd Packets <= 0.000043 AND Fwd Packet Length Max > 0.00021549999999999998)

2.(Fwd Packet Length Max <=0.00021549999999999998)

IF these condition are true i want to write attack in "Activity" column, and then write the whole file into a new csv with the activity

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao6HK.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
import codecs
import csv

main_labels=["Total Length of Fwd Packets","Fwd Packet Length Max","Flow Bytes/s","Label","Activity"]


df = pd.read_csv('portscanfeatures.csv',usecols=main_labels)

attack_or_not=[]

for i in df["Fwd Packet Length Max"]:#it changes the normal label to "1" and 

the attack tag to "0" for use in the machine learning algorithm

if i <= 0.00021549999999999998:
    attack_or_not.append(1)
else:
    attack_or_not.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Just make a list of conditions, then use numpy.where to put the needed values.

```
import numpy as np

conditions = ((df['Total Length of Fwd Packets'] <= 0.00003225) & (df['Total Length of Fwd Packets'] <= 0.000043) & (df['Fwd Packet Length Max'] > 0.00021549999999999998) & (df['Fwd Packet Length Max'] <=0.00021549999999999998))

df['attack'] = np.where(conditions, 'Attack', "Don't")

#or if you want 1, 0 directly

df['attack'] = np.where(conditions, 1, 0)
```